# Convert StringBuilder output directly to InputSream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working through a complex flow where I need to:

Step 1. Read a user provided file (from UI).

Step 2. Store the content into a `StringBuilder` (after doing some formatting changes).

Step 3. Convert the above `StringBuilder` output to a `InputStream`.

Step 4. Pass this `InputStream` to `S3 API` in order to store the file in S3.

The problem:
At Step 3, I am having to store the output into another physical file. And then get the `InputStream` from that file to proceed further. This extra step of creating an additional file seems unnecessary to me
and I wish to directly convert my `StringBuilder` output to input stream.

The code:

**TextFormatterUtil.java**

```
    /**
     * Convert given file to delimited text file input stream
     *
     * @param file file to be converted
     * @return delimited text input stream
     */
    public InputStream convertFileToText(MultipartFile file) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0);
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file.getInputStream());
        Sheet firstSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        for (Row nextRow : firstSheet) {
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case STRING:
                        sb.append(cell.getStringCellValue()).append("\t");
                        break;
                    case BOOLEAN:
                        sb.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue()).append("\t");
                        break;
                    case NUMERIC:
                        sb.append(cell.getNumericCellValue()).append("\t");
                        break;
                    case FORMULA:
                        sb.append(cell.getCellFormula()).append("\t");
                        break;
                    default:
                        log.debug("Failed to read the content of the cell [{}] ", cell);
                }
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        wb.close();

        return dumpStringBuilderToOutputStream(sb);
    }

    /**
     * Efficiently dump string builder to a file
     *
     * @param sb string builder
     * @throws IOException exception
     * @return target file input stream
     */
    private static FileInputStream dumpStringBuilderToOutputStream(StringBuilder sb) throws IOException {
        File targetFile = getFile("classpath:targetFile.txt"); // Not ideal!!!

        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(targetFile))) {
            final int aLength = sb.length();
            final int aChunk = 1024;
            final char[] aChars = new char[aChunk];

            for (int aPosStart = 0; aPosStart < aLength; aPosStart += aChunk) {
                final int aPosEnd = Math.min(aPosStart + aChunk, aLength);
                sb.getChars(aPosStart, aPosEnd, aChars, 0);
                bw.write(aChars, 0, aPosEnd - aPosStart);
            }
            bw.flush();
        }

        return new FileInputStream(targetFile);
    }
```

**DocumentService.java**

```
    public void uploadDocument(DocumentDto documentDto) throws GenericException {
        MultipartFile documentFile = documentDto.getFile();

        InputStream targetStream = textFormatterUtil.convertFileToText(documentFile);
        // Store stream to S3
        s3Client.putObject(createPutDocumentFileRequest(targetStream, savedDocument, documentRefKey));
    }

    /**
     * Creates put request for object store.
     *
     * @param documentInputStream document input stream
     * @param document document entity
     * @param documentRefKey document reference key
     * @return put object request
     */
    private PutObjectRequest createPutDocumentFileRequest(InputStream documentInputStream, DocumentEntity document, String documentRefKey) {
        S3ObjectMetadata metadata = new S3ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.addUserMetadata(METADATA_PROPERTY_FILE_NAME.getText(), document.getFileName());
        metadata.setContentType(document.getFileType());
        PutObjectRequest req = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, documentRefKey, documentInputStream);
        req.withObjectMetadata(metadata);

        return req;
    }
```

Is there any way I can avoid creating an extra file?

Comment: Quickest I can think of is `return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());`. But chances are you don't even need the intermediate `StringBuilder` object, depending on how you're processing `file`. Can you show that too?

Comment: @ernest_k Added full code.